# Semaphore blocking UI thread in iOS on customSearchBar?.placeholder

Tags: ios, swift, semaphore, freeze

I am running into a weird issue where my UI is blocking due to a semaphore caused when setting the searchbar placeholder. Please see the image below.

[image]

This is what is happening on other threads.
  [image]

Comment: Is there anything of note on any other thread while this is happening?

Comment: I have updated the post about the other threads . kindly check.

Comment: No, that isn't what I asked. At the time that the main thread is stuck on a semaphore, what is happening on the other threads. Your update is not from a time when the main thread is stuck. And you need to look at all threads at that time.

Comment: I understood your question and the posted images are exactly of the time when the thread is stuck.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the new picture. It looked like the top stack was thread 1 but it is actually thread 4.

Comment: I do not see any sane reason for this issue to happen . Can you suggest something that could cause this to happen?